# Tomcat 5.5 (.20) Start keeps stalling - stdout log stops @ "Initializing Performance Management"

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat5.5

Does anyone have any idea what causes the restart of Tomcat 5.5 to stop at this?

The lines before it I have seen before during successful restarts, but they could hold more information:

> INFO: XML validation disabled log4j:WARN No appenders could be found
>   for logger (org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.sax). log4j:WARN
>   Please initialize the log4j system properly. log4j:WARN No appenders
>   could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.sax).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

I have made changes to conf/server.xml to include SSL keystore settings in the  string for port 8443 but even when I comment this out, the same issue occurs.

Either way, the service says it is running but I cannot access either of the ports 8080 or 8443.

Any help would be greatful, thankyou.

Comment: Warnings do not stop Tomcat from (re)starting. However, fixing log4j *may* result in more clear logging which in turn should give more insights what's causing Tomcat to stall.

Comment: I restarted the server and it seemed to fix whatever problem was occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted the server and it seemed to fix whatever problem was occurring, though I cannot explain what was causing the error above.